# DIY Powered USB Hub PCB

Tags: pcb, diy, usb-hub

For my home project I need to connect multiple Arduino's to a Raspberry Pi. My raspberry pi controls everything in my house and the arduino's are going to be used to get sensor data.

I want to connect multiple Arduino's (up to maybe 20 or more) and I think it will be best to use a powered usb hub to do that (connected to the raspberry pi and use serial communication to get the data at the Raspberry Pi). To make it as best for my case I would like to build a PCB so I can make it exactly as I want, the only question is... how.

I have made multiple PCB's but I don't have a degree in it, I just want to make it for my hobby, can someone help me to start with it, or is it too difficult or can't it be done?

Comment: Have you got the system working with a commercial hub yet? How are you going to identify the Arduinos?

Comment: I have connected an Arduino to a cheap usb hub and I can identify every connected usb device and give it a unique name, so far that worked, also here it is confirmed: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/12109

Comment: I'll be honest, getting commercial USB hubs will be a) more reliable and b) cheaper than building these yourself. It's what I, an engineer, would do.

Comment: Well, I can understand it will be cheaper, the only "problem" is that it will be more difficult to make it fit the way I want. Making a pcb makes it more expandable and fit my 19" server rack

Comment: oh, I thought you were space-constrained... 19" rack doesn't sound like that at all.

Comment: Btw, USB doesn't allow for arbitrarily deep hub "trees", so make sure your architecture works before pulling cables.

Comment: Could you explain to me what deep hub "trees" means? I have never heard of this and don't know what it is. An alternative hub (as not making my own pcb) is this: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000291584825.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.30c03c00PJZ4rk&mp=1. Is this something you mean?

Comment: I think Marcus means that you can't keep connecting hubs to hubs and keep getting more ports (I think people start seeing issues after connecting ~5 hubs in series?). Bandwidth and latency also becomes an issue when you have a large number of devices on a single bus. tl;dr: wire everything up and test first.

Comment: Keep in mind distance limitations with USB, is there any reason why you need 20 different arduinos all within 30 feet of your main raspberry pi? Yes, with a boosted signal cable you can get reliably up to 50 feet but the cost of those cables alone are going to jack up your price so much...

Comment: USB allows 7 levels of hubs, including your computer, the actual device, and possibly a hub inside the device. So that leaves 4 levels of hubs. 10-port hubs are probably 3 hubs in series (using up either 2 or 3 levels). There is also a maximum of 127 devices on a tree (some devices are multiple devices, and this includes hubs). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub

Answer (score 1):

I would also advise against doing a USB hub if you're not familiar with PCB design. As mentioned in the comments already, you're much better off getting a commercially made USB hub.

PCB design involving high speed busses like USB usually need special consideration when laying out the board (like impedance matching, trace length matching, reducing cross-talk , etc). If you're not careful, you might end up with a hub that only works with USB 1.1, one that's unreliable, or not functional at all.

If you really want to give it a go, find a USB hub chip that fits your requirements using the parametric parts selector of your favourite electronic parts distributor. The datasheet for the chip usually contains a schematic of a reference design that you can use in your design.

Comment: I assume that Arduinos only speak full speed USB 1, so it's an insanely high speed.

Comment: Does anyone have some information how to start? I would like to try it as a hobby, i am not sure if it will be reliable but i would like to try

Comment: @Bluebird Like I mentioned, pick a USB hub chip, and use the reference design in its data sheet as a starting point. Also, [the electrical specs of USB](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml#Electrical) is useful background reading, as well as how differential signalling works in general.